# Char* array not retaining value C

Tags: c, string, char

For my networking class, we're building a bittorrent client based off the UDP protocol, which is pretty cool but I'm having a ton of trouble with C strings for some reasons.

The first time I receive a packet, I do:

```
if(server_data == NULL){
    server_data = malloc(one_block.total_blocks*sizeof(char*));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < one_block.total_blocks; i++){
        server_data[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
        server_data[i] = "";
    }
}
```

Here, server_data is a `char**` and one_block is `struct` that holds packet information and the payload.

Next I do:

```
server_data[one_block.which_block] = one_block.payload;
blocks_rcv++;
if(blocks_rcv == one_block.total_blocks-1)
    done = TRUE; //macro
if(done){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < one_block.total_blocks; i++){
        printf("%s", server_data[i];
    }
}
```

All seems well and dandy but for whatever insane reason when I print the contents of server_data before all the packets are received, I see different data from each packet. Afterwards I set done = TRUE and go into that for loop, every spot in the array contains the same string value.

I have no idea why this is happening and I really want to understand how from the beginning of the post to the end, the contents of the array change, even though I verify them through every iteration of the loop that reads in one packet at a time.

Comment: `server_data[i] = ""; /* memory leak */`

Comment: If you do `malloc(sizeof(char*));` you only allocate four or eight bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
server_data[i] = "";
```

It *overwrites* the allocated pointer, with a pointer to the string literal. And as string literals can't be modified, if you later copy into this pointer, you experience *undefined behavior*.

If you want to make sure the string is empty, either use `calloc`, set the first character to `'\0'`, or use `strcpy` to *copy* in the new string.

Comment: @shadow Then you need to show what you do _between_ you allocate and you print.

Comment: That is what I do. That's it.

Comment: @shadow You mean you allocate the string, then print them directly after? You don't actually load them with anything?

Comment: Those two blocks of code I posted? They come one after the other. And yeah of course I do, I set server_data = one_block.payload.

Comment: @shadow The statement `server_data[one_block.which_block] = one_block.payload;` is _yet again_ changing the pointer to point to something else completely. And _what is_ `one_block.payload`? What does it contain? Is it properly terminated?

Comment: yeah it's a char*, terminated and all, but let me use strcpy and see what happens

Comment: I literally love you right now. It was a combination of only allocating space for a char* and not using strcpy. Please be my stackoverflow life partner.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues going on here:

1) First, server_data, if it's declared as a char**, may or may not be null off the bat, unless you declare it so.  I'm not sure if you initialized it to NULL or not.  It's a good idea to explicitly initialize it to NULL.

2) I'm not sure from what's going on if you intend for each item of the array server_data to hold a char* (in other words, a reference to a string), or for the array to be a string itself.  Is one_block.payload a string, or a set of pointers to strings?

I ran your code with some test values and I'm personally not getting any problems with unexpected values...I think the issue may be in how the struct that holds your payload data is set up.  Could you show us your one_block struct?  What type of variable/array is one_block.payload?

Comment: Thanks but I already figured it out thanks to @Joachim Pileborg. It had to do with not mallocing the right amount and not using strcpy.